# Как получить src сслыку чтобы заменить href сслыку?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<a id="img-1" href="https://static.example1.com/images/img1.png">
 <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://proxy.example2.com/.../img1.png">
</a>
<a id="img-2" href="https://static.example1.com/images/img2.png">
 <img class="img-thumbnail"  src="https://proxy.example2.com/.../img2.png"
</a>
```

Как получить src у изображения, но при этом заменив обе href ссылки на соответствующие src ссылки?(и замена ссылок должна происходить со стороны клиента и если будет jQuery то ничего страшного)

Пробовал:

```
var imgsrc = document.getElementsByClassName("img-thumbnail").src;
document.getElementById("img-1").src=imgsrc;
```

Но это полностью бесполезно, хотя на что было надеяться.
Если честно, но хз как это реализовать.

Comment: Не `getElementByClassName`, а `getElementsByClassName`. И возвращает он массив.

Comment: @XelaNimed что за чушь? Он возвращает `HTMLCollection`, в этом можно легко убедиться: `document.getElementsByClassName('img-thumbnail') instanceof HTMLCollection`. Плюс к тому он не имеет как минимум метода `forEach`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, был не прав с массивом, но в любом случае нет такого метода у документа как `getElementByClassName`. Массив, коллекция... Главный посыл был в возвращении множества, а не единичного элемента.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.img-thumbnail');
imgs.forEach(el => el.closest('a').href = el.src);
```

Answer (score 3):

На jq вот так вот можно. Заходим в каждую картинку, берем ее src, и ее родителю меняем href.

```js
$('.img-thumbnail').each(function() {
  let src = $(this).attr('src');
  
  $(this).parents('a').attr('href', src);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="img-1" href="https://static.example1.com/images/img1.png">
 <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://proxy.example2.com/.../img1.png">
</a>
<a id="img-2" href="https://static.example1.com/images/img2.png">
 <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://proxy.example2.com/.../img2.png">
</a>
```